# Allow merging Q&A from a private Team to public, preserving all comments and votes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is there a feature or will it be in the future to merge some QA of your private SO for teams to regular SO with all comments and upvotes?

I can imagine a situation when a company decides to make proprietary library open source, this feature could be really helpful as I see.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no such feature at the moment (we've locked everything down for security). But in theory, we could enable question migrations to public Stack Overflow from a team. I think we just need to measure demand for such a thing before enabling it, as there is an obvious security tradeoff with someone accidentally using such a feature as well.

Off the top of my head, if this is something many people want, we'll need to put some effort into:

- Making it super clear what's happening (double confirmation, etc.)
- Making sure it can't be abused (e.g. reputation exploits)
- Deciding what the targets are, likely only public Stack Overflow here
- Deciding who can do it (all users? admins? guides and admins?)
- Probably adding a team/admin setting allowing it at all

We have thought about this, but want to see actual cases come up before considering it much further. For example, what if a company has a few teams, and we need to move a question between teams? The same case would exist in our Enterprise installs as well. I think there's similar cases in *private→private* alongside *private→public*, but both would be similar code with only the targets list differing.

Comment: and then there are the social aspects, and how the community might react when a Team throws over a bunch of not so excellent content. The odds that internal Q&A content won't satisfy the SO rules are quite high.

Comment: Mmm seems to me the migration of votes & rep would be problematic. They probably mean more/less in microcosm and can't just be transferred fairly? Better than it was with Documentation though I suppose where rep just had a totally different meaning and scale :P

Comment: OTOH, it's not unreasonable to believe that had the team been using SO main from the get-go (i.e. like some companies do for questions about their product) that a Q&A would have gotten those the views and votes which it did while part of a team. What's missing is the *additional* views/answers/comments/up-/down-/close-votes which the Q&A would have received had it been on SO main from when it was first posted.

Comment: Many teams sites become more of a discussion board until they settle on the official answer, I would support this feature to "publish" / "promote" or "re-post" individual teams questions and their single answer as a new public wiki QA post. It would be nice to see the linkage between the two but posting as public wiki should reduce rep exploitation. Maybe both the OP and author of the answer should provide consent? And then an Admin must approve the post as being free of any IP they do not wish to disclose before it officially makes it into public SO... That's how I would see it working